# Access MVC session from web service

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

First of all let me say that I`ve searched for solutions but I found only the way how to enable session in Web Api which is not what I'm looking for.

Here's what I need. What`s the best approach to achieve this in mvc. Let's say I have MVC shop application. I also have mobile app which uses web api to access my application. Let's say user added 2 items to cart, then he had to left and decided to continue his shopping with mobile app. He added 2 more items. So he should have 4 in a cart. Then he came back home, he refreshes his page and it shows him that there are 4 items in cart. So... What's the best approach to share cart between web api and mvc project. I don't want to store it only in database and read/write all the time to database.

Second quesion. Is there any option to let know mobile app that user had just added something to his cart without mobile app pinging web api for this kind of information all the time?

Comment: Actually, it's better to use a database for this. If you're using InProc session then the app can't scale. And if you use SQL Session then... you're using a database on top of a framework. Better to store the user's session in json in a database in a key/value table: key is UserID (or SessionID) and value is a json string that contains the session data. Put an index on the key so that perf is a non-issue: if you and then your app can easily scale.

Answer (score 0):

If you're serious about this, I think you should consider both the MVC application as the Web API as application layers, whose main responsibility is to present the data in different formats. In the business layer beneath you store the shopping cart, user information and so on, and for that purpose a database is a really good choice. Flat file storage is also an option, but one that lacks efficient concurrency handling etc.

In-memory storage, on the other hand, is a really bad idea since that data won't survive a restart of the web application / Web API.

Answer (score 0):

from your description of the problem im assuming you are saving session in memory. Which is not a very good practice as after using this you will not be able to scale your web app to multiple servers and if you do it you will have to maintain sticky sessions.

On the contrary if you keep the session out the the server memory you
 
1. Can scale well 
2. Share session state between multiple services which is more suitable to your senario.
3. Can very easily update the state/info the one device has about the user's session.

For the second part of your question there are multiple technologies you can use to share this session state with multiple devices.

1. polling (that you probably are doing right now)

2. long polling (keeping a continuous connection with the server. imitation long connected state)

3. Socket Connection

4. Push technologies (**Most Preferred** in your case)

 For a more complete and end to end solution you can also look out for websites like [firebase.com](http://www.firebase.com) which give you a solution that handles the case you mention here.

Answer (score 0):

There are basically two ways to do this.

You can't use session, or cookies, because you're going to have multiple sessions and multiple clients, so the session won't be the same and the cookies won't be the same.

If you're only using one server, then you could use .net runtime cache to store the data, keyed on user id.  However, this can still get lost when the app pool is recycled.

Your best bet is to store the data in the database.  I know you said you don't want to, but your reason (not wanting to constantly access the database) is not a good reason to avoid it, since there are many ways to minimize database access.

The simplest method is to use a combination of database and cache.  So, you check the cache for the cart, and if it's there, you use it.  If not, you load it from the database and put it in the cart.

This solves several problems, and makes it more scalable to multiple servers, and makes it faster since it's only checking the database once.  You do, however, have to write to the database and the cache whenever the cart is updated.

You may still have some cache coherency issues of you're using multiple servers and multiple devices... for instance, if you use both devices at the same time, they might be on different servers, and have different cache entries.. but there are ways to solve that too.

As for your second question, your best bet is to use SignalR to send a message to your mobile app when the cart is updated.